# How to get a specific length of string in my array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am generating an integer from 5-10.

once I generate an integer ranging from 5-10, the loop should choose a string on my array that has a `character length` based on the random integer that is generated.

example:

random integer generated: `10`

the system should display a string that has a length of `10 character` so either it will display the `testNames1` or `testNames2` because it has `10 character length`

I tried doing this on my code, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
  function getName(){

    $names = array(
        'Juans',
        'Luisss',
        'Pedroaa',
        'testNames1',
        'testNames2',
        'testName3',
        'test', //This should not be return because im only generating a number random of 5-10 and this character has only 4 character length
        'tse', //This should not be return because im only generating a number random of 5-10 and this character has only 3 character length
        // and so on
    );
    
    $randomString = "";
    
    for ($i = 0; $i <count($names); $i++) {
        $value = rand(5,10);
        $length_string = strlen($names[$i]);

        if ($value == $length_string) {
            return "name:".$names[$i].$value;
        }
 
    }

  }

echo getName();
?>
```

Can anyone help me on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is first create a list of strings matching the length and then pick a random one from them.  So loop through all of the strings, check the length and add to `$match`, then use `array_rand()` to pick one of the matching ones...

```
function getName($random_num)
{
    $names = array
    (
        'Juans',
        'Luisss',
        'Pedroaa',
        'testNames1',
        'testNames2',
        'testName3',
        'test', //This should not be return because im only generating a number random of 5-10 and this character has only 4 character length
        'tse', //This should not be return because im only generating a number random of 5-10 and this character has only 3 character length
        // and so on
    );
    $randomString = "";
    $match = [];
    foreach ( $names as $name )
    {
        $length_string = strlen($name);
        if ($random_num == $length_string)
        {
            $match[] = $name;
        }
    }
    // If non found return ''
    return !empty($match) ? $match[array_rand($match)] : '';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. this helps me a lot Sir! I already understand my mistake, this solves too the choosing of one value in multiple value that has same length of character! thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code. You was adding the below line in the loop that was wrong.

```
$value = rand(5,10);
```

Now, This program will return the name that will be equal to the generated random number that is between 5 to 10. Also it will return the message if no name exist according to the random number. For example: 8

```
<?php
function getName($random_num)
{
    $names = array
    (
        'Juans',
        'Luisss',
        'Pedroaa',
        'testNames1',
        'testNames2',
        'testName3',
        'test', //This should not be return because im only generating a number random of 5-10 and this character has only 4 character length
        'tse', //This should not be return because im only generating a number random of 5-10 and this character has only 3 character length
        // and so on
    );
    $randomString = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i <count($names); $i++)
    {
        $length_string = strlen($names[$i]);
        if ($random_num == $length_string)
        {
            return "name:".$names[$i].$random_num;
        }
    }
}
$random_num = rand(5,10);
$returned_name = getName($random_num);
if ($returned_name == "")
{
    echo "No Name Exist having length: " . $random_num;
}
else
{
    echo $returned_name;
}
?>
```

Comment: OH! I WAS SO CLOSE ON MY PROBLEM! :(. THANK YOU VERY MUCH SIR! I APPREICATE IT SO MUCH

Comment: sir can i still ask, what if there is 2 string that has a same lenght of character? how can i randomly choose 1 from them?

Comment: This program will return only the first one from the array. It will not return 2 values.

Comment: is there a way sir to randomly choose one from the 2 values that has same length?

Comment: Yes, in that case you have to return the array from the function. and after that use the array_rand function to select one key from the array randomly

Answer (score 1):

you are almost there ... you just need to generate random number outside then make checks like this :

```
<?php
function getName($random_num)
{
    $matches= [];
    $names = array(
        'Juans',
        'Luisss',
        'Pedroaa',
        'testNames1',
        'testNames2',
        'testName3',
        'test', //This should not be return because im only generating a number random of 5-10 and this character has only 4 character length
        'tse', //This should not be return because im only generating a number random of 5-10 and this character has only 3 character length
        // and so on
    );

    $value = rand(5,10);
  
    for ($i = 0; $i <count($names); $i++) {
       
        if(strlen($names[$i]) == $value)
        {
            $matches[] = $names[$i];
          
        }
    }
 
    print_r($matches);
}

?>
```